# Dash plotly fetch data real time using scheduler

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am building a dashboard with Dash plotly. I need to fetch data from elasticsearch endpoint on real-time. I created a function `def data_loading()` to connect to endpoint and query data. It will return data as a pandas DataFrame.
However, when execute the dash app, it will execute the data_loading() function once.

I want to schedule the function data_loading() every 10 minutes to query the new data in database.
I am using apscheduler but I dont know how to return the dataframe on scheduling.
Below is my code:

```
def data_loading():
   return df
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=data_loading, trigger="interval", seconds=5)
scheduler.start()
```

Is there anyway I can get the df after each scheduler job?

Comment: I tried `scheduler.add_listener()` as well but it did not work. Is there any idea how to do that efficiently?

Comment: Where does the dataframe need to go? What didn't work with your listener? Perhaps see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Lucan I need to return the dataframe for showing in dashboard later. The flow is: query data from database -> dataframe -> use data in dataframe to plot charts and table -> showing on dashboard (using Dash). But I need to query the data on real time, then I want to schedule the function data_loading() every 10 minutes using apscheduler (the code in my question). But it just can run the scheduling job, the dataframe didn't change. I am new to this and I am not sure this is the right way to do this or not?